# How to place the date icon after the date picker input in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 and can not get the date icon to appear after the date selection input. It is appearing under it.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<form data-toggle="validator" class="container-fluid" role="form" id="gymUpdateForm">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 beta container-fluid">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-12" for="updateDescription">Description:<span class="req"> *</span></label>
                    <div class="controls col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-12">
                        <input type="text" id="updateDescription" name="updateDescription" placeholder="Description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-2" for="updateArchive">Archived:</label>
                    <div class="date col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-12" id="datepicker1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control fullWidth" id="updateArchive" name="updateArchive" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:#ddd;">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="padding:5px;"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">                 
            <button type="submit" id="updateGym" class="btn btn-large btn-warning" >Update</button>
            <button type="button" id="cancelGym" class="btn btn-large btn-warning" >Return</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If it weren't appearing at all, and since you're using BootStrap 5 (I still prefer Bootstrap 4, and I strongly believe the overwhelming number of web UIs simply benefit from jQuery - no ifs/ands/buts), I'd suggest substituting `fas fa-calendar`: [Font Awesome 5 Date & Time Icons](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_icons_datetime.asp).  Q: Have you tried putting `<input>` and `<i>` both inside the same `<span>`?

Comment: Tried this and did not changes: <input type="text" class="form-control fullWidth" id="updateArchive" name="updateArchive" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: input-group

```
<div class="input-group date col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-12" id="datepicker1">
```

Comment: You *HAD* "input-group" ... but you put it in the wrong div, correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 The answer relates to the <div with id="datepicker1". That is the one I added 'input-group' to :-). I will also change the class fa to fas, as you suggested. Kind regards, Glyn

Answer (score 0):

When I copy this code into my editor the *#ddd* background shows immediately next to the date input box, not below it. However, the background only is showing, no calendar icon, which is strange. This might be because the *Class* prefix for it should be *FAS* rather than *FA* (*FA* is an older version of Font Awesome).

Comment: I tried fas and fas-calendar. The fas does not change the display and fas-calendar does not display the icon. I am using <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">

Comment: In Font Awesome 5 the prefix is definitely FAS. The thing is, I also struggled to reproduce your error. Although the icon didn't display, the box for it does indeed appear at the right hand side of your input box rather than appearing underneath it.

Comment: @Glyn - `fas-calendar` is *WRONG*.  You want "fa-calendar" ... but the Bootstrap 5 classname is now "fas" instead of "fa": `<i class="fas fa-calendar"...>`.